# Python 2.7: how to append lines which contain both string & numeric values to text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want **to append** following line to my text file:

Degree of polarization is 8.23 % and EVPA is 45.03 degree.

i.e. I want both string and numeric values to be appended.

I want to append above line with different numeric values after each run of my python code.

Any help will be appreciated.

For example

```
>>> a = 10.5 
>>> with open("myfile.txt","a") as f:
...  f.write(a)
```

gives me error.

Comment: Please do read the Python tutorial before asking basic questions like these. String formatting for output is [covered in a dedicated chapter](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Please do read carefully before giving your comment. I am asking not about string formating. My question is related to appending.

Comment: What difficulty are you having?

Comment: Why are you not able to append?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: I want to try  with open("myfile.txt","a") as f: What should be next code line? What does f.write() will contain ?

Comment: @atom Put that in your question.

Comment: @atom: the tutorial still answers your question. Why not read that carefully?

Comment: @atom What error are you dealing with? I imagine it's that you can't write a float to the file. You have to convert it to a string first, which is what my answer below is telling you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
while True:
    polarization = getPolarization()
    evpa = getEvpa()
    my_text = "Degree of polarization is {} % and EVPA is {} degree.".format(polarization, evpa)

    with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(my_text)
```

Maybe you should also write what have you tried yet and what problems/errors occurred

Answer (score 0):

You can only write strings to files.

Strings can be concatenated:

```
>>> 'a' + 'b'
'ab'
```

Numbers can be converted to strings:

```
>>> str(4)
'4'

>>> str(5.6)
'5.6'
```

You should be able to get started with that.

Also, Python's string formatting will automatically do this for you:

```
>>> '{} % and {} degree'.format(6.7, 8.9)
'6.7 % and 8.9 degree'
```

Or with a more readable format using keywords:

```
>>> '{polarization} % and {evpa} degree'.format(polarization=6.7, evpa=8.9)
'6.7 % and 8.9 degree'
```

Comment: My question is NOT related to string formating. It is related to appending lines to text file.

Comment: You can only write strings to files so you need to convert the values first. Your question isn't particularly clear. What difficulty do you have?